# How to query excel file in php?

Tags: php

I want to compare the 1st column of two excel files and if a match is found, I need to copy value of the 5th column to another excel sheet. I've tried `php_excel_reader` and `php_excel_writer` but with no success.

I want something like this:

```
excelF1;
excelF2;
for ($i=1; $i<=rowlength(excelF1); $i++)
{
    val1 = excelF1[i][1];
    for ($j=1; $j<=rowlength(excelF2); $j++)
    {
        val2 = excelF2[j][1];
        if(val1 == val2)
        {
            val3 = excelF2[j][5];
            //insert val3 into last column of excelF1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please define "no success" related to php_excel_*

Comment: means i tried php_excel_reader and php_excel_writer but couldn't find and way to address my problem, maybe i overlooked..

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and the [PHPExcel Examples](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)
or more lightweight [php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/wiki/Documentation) (for xls only)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i used R instead and that was pretty easy.

Comment: unusual but ok ;)   with phpexcel its pretty easy too

Answer (score -2):

try fgetcsv() and fputcsv() function.

document:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php